# ServiceStack Restful request using specific json

Tags: c#, servicestack

I need to create a request using `Service stack` that generates this `JSON` request:

```
[
    "ABC1234",
    "ABC5678",
    "ABC9122"
]
```

I tried this:

```
[Route("/getconsignments/{ConsignmentNumbers}", "POST")]
public class GetConsignments : IReturn<PublishManifestResponse>
{
    public string[] ConsignmentNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class PublishManifestResponse
{   
    [DataMember(Name = "ManifestNumber")]
    public string ManifestNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "ManifestedConnotes")]
    public string[] ManifestedConnotes { get; set; }
}
```

But it is not generating the request I need working.

Also,

How do I fill the json data in the request?

```
var request = new List<string>();
request.Add("abcd");
reuqest.Add("wewwq");

var client = new Client(new JsonServiceClient(appSettings.GetString("host")));
var result = client.GetConsignments(request.ToArray());
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept a batched request by [inheriting from a generic List](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-batched-requests#defining-a-request-dto-to-accept-a-collection-of-types), e.g:

```
[Route("/getconsignments/{ConsignmentNumber}", "POST")]
public class GetConsignments : List<string>, IReturn<PublishManifestResponse> 
{
    public string ConsignmentNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And if you need to return a JSON collection use `IReturn<string[]>`.

This will let you accept a Request conceptually similar to:

```
POST /getconsignments/1
[
    "ABC1234",
    "ABC5678",
    "ABC9122"
]
```

You shouldn't have complex types like a `string[]` in the `/path/info` portion of the route, if you also need to send `ConsignmentNumbers[]` in addition to the Request Body it should be specified on the QueryString instead which you'll need to remove from the Route, e.g:

```
[Route("/getconsignments", "POST")]
public class GetConsignments : List<string>, IReturn<PublishManifestResponse> 
{
    public string[] ConsignmentNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Which will accept requests like:

```
POST /getconsignments?ConsignmentNumbers=1,2,3
[
    "ABC1234",
    "ABC5678",
    "ABC9122"
]
```

But if you just need the JSON array, you would just have an empty Request DTO definition, e.g:

```
[Route("/getconsignments", "POST")]
public class GetConsignments : List<string>, IReturn<PublishManifestResponse> {}
```

To accept requests like:

```
POST /getconsignments
[
    "ABC1234",
    "ABC5678",
    "ABC9122"
]
```

Comment: What about the parameter?

public string[] ConsignmentNumbers { get; set; }

Comment: @RogerOliveira that's not in the request json you've shown, it's just a collection of strings.

Comment: your code is missing one '>' signal? also, my request is a JSON in that format ["abc", "cded", "werwer"]

Comment: @RogerOliveira I've updated my answer with valid examples as you provided an unusual Route definition.

Comment: thanks, actually I don't need that ConsignmentNumbers, only the json.

Comment: @RogerOliveira ok then my final example should cover it.

Comment: ok, and what is this: List<string>, IReturn<PublishManifestResponse> {}

should I include this List<string> ? my return should only be PublishManifestResponse... how do I fill the request?

Comment: @RogerOliveira What's in `IReturn<T>` is irrelevant to the Request DTO definition which describes what the Service accepts, `IReturn<T>` should match whatever your Service returns.

Comment: as I don't have any property in the request route, how do I add my request values (json)?

Comment: @RogerOliveira add properties? you mean access the JSON array values? the Request DTO is already a `List<string>` so you can treat it as such.

Comment: I added in the end of my question another example, and a question I have of how to add the json as parameter?? client is my class where the requests are.. but that code generates an error, I need to send the request to the method, how to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141398/discussion-between-roger-oliveira-and-mythz).

Comment: @RogerOliveira please ask any new questions in a new specific question, this answer is specific to the server impl and already covers too many questions.